# Is there any way to find out which user has tried to access specific file and got permission denied error

Tags: permissions

I want to know which user has tried to access specific file and consequently got permission denied error. Is there any way to do that in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

No. A simple failure to `open` a file is a process-related issue, not a system issue. The process trying to `open` the file is the only one that knows the `open` failed.

Since "permission denied" is a valid return status, and happens often, it's not logged.

Comment: But it is not a good thing, sometimes we encounter this failure and we want to know for what reason this failure has happened

Comment: My `pathlld` tool ( https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld ) will help you explore permissions. It's  a `bash` script, be sure to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can configure rules to do what you're asking with auditd(auditctl).

I can't help with it beyond this, because my only experience with it was shutting it off when it was killing my machine due to the excessive logging. But they seem to have solved this problem (at least back then): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220250/using-auditd-to-capture-permission-denied-notices